# Significato di "essere messo/a bene" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *La coscienza di Zeno*, di Italo Svevo, ho letto questo passaggio riferito agli affari commerciali del suocero di Zeno, l'io narrante (grassetto mio):

> Io ero la persona più importante per lui a quel tavolo. Mi confidò suoi segreti commerciali ch’io mai tradii. La sua fiducia **era messa benissimo**, tant’è vero che poté ingannarmi due volte, quand’ero già divenuto suo genero. La prima volta la sua accortezza mi costò bensì del denaro, ma fu l'Olivi ad esser l’ingannato e perciò io non mi dolsi troppo.

Ora, alla [voce "mettere" del vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mettere/), ho trovato:

> Di cose, con gli avv. *bene* o *male*, avviarsi a buona o cattiva riuscita, prender buona o cattiva piega: *per ora, la faccenda mette bene*; *Male per voi, che bene per noi mette!* (Pascoli).

Non riesco però a capire il senso dell'espressione "la sua fiducia era messa benissimo" che appare nel brano sopra citato: il significato sarebbe che Zeno considera che la fiducia avuta del suocero in lui nel confidargli i suoi segreti commerciali ha giovato ottimamente agli affari del suocero?

Comment: "Messo bene" significa di solito "in buone condizioni", "in buono stato" ; nel brano in questione potrebbe significare che il grado di fiducia del suocero nei suoi confronti era ottimo. Un'altra interpretazione potrebbe essere che "messo" qui significhi "riposto" e quindi che la fiducia era ben riposta.

Comment: Condivido la seconda ipotesi di @RiccardoDeContardi: a orecchio direi che Zeno consideri “ben riposta” la fiducia del suocero: Zeno sa di essere onesto e sa anche che la sua onestà viene sfruttata dal suocero.

Comment: @DaG e Riccardo: Cioè, il senso sarebbe che il suocero aveva riposto la sua fiducia in Zeno nell'ultima accezione riportata alla [voce "riporre" sul vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riporre)?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: il mio commento precedente è una domanda anche per te.

Comment: @Charo sì. Corretto

Comment: Qualcuno può scrivere una risposta @DaG @RiccardoDeContardi? :)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Spero proprio che qualcuno possa: io e Riccardo stiamo solo esprimendo delle opinioni a orecchio (parlo per me, ma vedo che anche Riccardo dice “potrebbe significare”, “potrebbe essere”...).

Comment: L’espressione non è “mettere bene” ma “essere messo/a bene”. Il senso è: “essere riposta bene” come già notato sopra.

Comment: Va bene, @Hachi: modifico il titolo della domanda.

Answer (score 1):

Significa che lui si fidava molto del genero, di fatti sottolinea che tanto era grande la fiducia, che venne ingannato.

Nell’italiano attuale ed informale non utilizziamo questo tipo di espressioni. Semplicemente diciamo :” fidarsi di una persona - mi fido molto di lui”-
Contrariamente “tradire la fiducia di qualcuno” ha il significato opposto: (ha tradito la mia fiducia!)